# Кто сможет помочь с настройкой Elasticsearch для корректной выдачи результатов поиска?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Друзья, очень нужна помощь специалиста, знающего **Elasticsearch**. Как его настраивать.

На сервере подняли окружение, поставили Java + Elasticsearch, связали с Laravel 5. Поиск работает, но по коротким словам некорректно ищет.

**Задача: помочь настроить корректно выдачу по поисковым выражениям. Выдает очень неправильно некоторые результаты поиска**

*Например короткие слова "ВИЧ" (болезнь), "Тен" (фамилия) происходит поиск в длинных словах и может это слово искать как часть слова, например, ожидая получить результаты на тему "ВИЧ", можно получить все что угодно, в том числе "Прибыл Виталий Николаевич..."*

Поиск расположен по адресу: [Search form](http://tayga.info/search)

Искали специалистов на FL, Freelance. Готовы оплатить работу по настройке.

Собственно сам метод поисковой формы, вдруг по нему понятно будет в чем проблема:

```
/**
 * Search result page
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function search()
{
    $input = Input::get('query', null);
    $page = Input::get('page', 1);
    $perPage = 15;
    if ($input) {
        $start = ($page - 1) * $perPage;
        $params = [
            'index' => 'scout',
            'from' => $start,
            'size' => $perPage,
            'body' => [
                'query' => [
                    'multi_match' => [
                        'query' => $input,
                        'fields' => [
                            'title',
                            'summary',
                            'content'
                        ],
                        'fuzziness' => 'AUTO',
                    ],
                ],
                'sort' => [
                    'id' => [
                        'order' => 'desc'
                    ]
                ],
                'filter' => [
                    'term' => [
                        'status' => 1
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];

        $elastic = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
        $result = $elastic->search($params);

        $result = $result['hits'];

        if (empty($result['hits'])) {
            return view('search-form');
        }

        $totalResults = $result['total'];
        $totalPages = ceil($totalResults / $perPage);
        if ($page > $totalPages) {
            $page = $totalPages;
        }

        // Get news IDs for laravel search
        $ids = [];
        foreach ($result['hits'] as $item) {
            $ids[] = $item['_id'];
        }

        $news = News::whereIn('id', $ids)
            ->orderBy('published', 'desc')
            ->get();

        return view('search-result')
            ->with('title', $input)
            ->with('news', $news)
            ->with('page', $page)
            ->with('totalResults', $totalResults)
            ->with('totalPages', $totalPages)
            ->render();
    }

    return view('search-form');
}
```

Данный метод с параметрами находит список ID, потом по ним в БД смотрит и выводит их с сортировкой. Это кстати тоже очень криво реализовано. Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Для понимания что происходит внутри нужен маппинг для индекса scout. Добавьте, если можно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему маппинг для полей, по которым идет поиск, динамический. В приведенном маппинге поля 'title', 'summary', 'content' в типе authenticable имеют 'index' => 'not_analyzed' - поиск по ним бы в принципе не работал. Только полное совпадение.

При динамическом маппинге строковых поллей используется стандартный анализатор, который реализует алгоритм сегментации текста Unicode. Что превращает большие тексты в кашу токенов. Поэтому поиск ведет себя непредсказуемо. 'fuzziness' => 'AUTO' только ухудшает ситуацию, при поиске слов длиннее двух символов.

Вторая ошибка это поля 'title', 'summary', 'content' в вашем запросе имеют одинаковый вес. Логичнее, что совпадение текста в заголовке статьи имеет большее значение, чем в контенте.

Чтобы исправить ситуацию нужно:

1. Настроить маппинг для соответсвующих полей. В примитивном случае это анализатор russian, из [примера в документации](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#russian-analyzer). Обязательно добавить стоп-слова.
2. Задать вес полей в маппинге или в запросе multi_match. Пример маппинга:

   ```
   'mappings' => [
       'newstype' => [
           'properties' => [
               'title' => [
                   'type' => 'string',
                   'analyzer' => 'russian',
                   'boost' => 3
               ],
               'summary' => [
                   'type' => 'string',
                   'analyzer' => 'russian',
                   'boost' => 1
               ],
               'content' => [
                   'type' => 'string',
                   'analyzer' => 'russian',
                   'boost' => 1
               ]
           ]
       ]
   ]
   ```
3. Немного изменить запрос. Использовать тот же анализатор, который использовался при индексации:

   ```
   'query' => [
           'multi_match' => [
               'query' => $input,
               'fields' => ['title', 'summary', 'content'],
               'analyzer' => 'russian',
           ],
   ]
   ```

Дальше нужна тонкая настройка в зависимости от данных и пожеланий. Я бы еще посоветовал использовать [плагин для русской морфологии](https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-analysis-morphology).

Comment: Спасибо большое, Андрей. В ближайшие несколько часов я обязательно это попробую исправить. Как я мог бы связаться с вами? наверняка были бы еще мелкие вопросы, конечно ваша консультация была бы не бесплатной. Я уверен, вы смогли бы помочь мне настроить поисковой движок как нужно )

Answer (score 0):

Вот код из файла **/config/scout.php**
На самом деле я сложно понимаю как настраивать мэпинг, правильно ли я его использую. У меня по прежнему короткие слова как попало ищет и выдает неверно результат, не релевантно.

```
'elasticsearch' => [
    'index' => env('ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX', 'scout'),
    'config' => [
        'hosts' => [
            env('ELASTICSEARCH_HOST', '127.0.0.1:9200'),
        ],
    ],
    'fields' => [
        'users_index' => [
            'title',
            'summary',
            'content',
        ],
    ],
    'indices' => [
        'scout' => [
            'settings' => [
                'number_of_shards' => 3,
                'number_of_replicas' => 2,
                "analysis" => [
                    "analyzer" => [
                        "synonym_filter" => [
                            "tokenizer" => "standard",
                            "filter" => ["lowercase", "synonym_filter"],
                        ]
                    ],
                    "filter" => [
                        "synonym_filter" => [
                            "type" => "synonym",
                            "synonyms_path" => "analysis/synonyms.txt",
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'mappings' => [
                'authenticable' => [
                    'properties' => [
                        'title' => [
                            'type' => 'string',
                            'index' => 'not_analyzed',
                        ],
                        'summary' => [
                            'type' => 'string',
                            'index' => 'not_analyzed',
                        ],
                        'content' => [
                            'type' => 'string',
                            'index' => 'not_analyzed',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```